# Jetpack Compose: Setting fixed height of parent view

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, size

I'm converting code to Jetpack Compose. Dimensions of a particular container in recycler view are set by API response.

ViewContainer:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="56dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="56dp"
        android:gravity="center"" />
```

Height setting code in ViewHolder:

```
                    container.layoutParams.height = item.containerHeight
//value of item.containerHeight is 600 dp
```

When I convert the code to the following Composable:

```
    Box(modifier = Modifier.height(item.containerHeight.dp).fillMaxWidth() {
    Text(
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center).padding(start = 56.dp, end = 56.dp),
            text = ...,
            fontFamily = ...,
            fontSize = 18 sp
    )
```

The resulting text box is over 6 times the size of the version created by the XML even though they are both being given the same value for the height (600 dp). Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify values programmatically in the `LayoutParams`, those values are expected to be pixels.

Convert pixels to Dp:

```
val dp = with(LocalDensity.current) {
  item.containerHeight.toDp()
}
```